# Delete dictionary key based on the condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary

```
d={2: [], 3: [], 5: [], 7: [], 11: [11], 13: [31], 17: [71], 19: [], 23: [], 29: [], 37: [73], 41: [], 43: [], 47: [], 53: [], 59: [], 61: [], 67: [], 79: [97], 83: [], 89: [], 101: [11, 101], 103: [13, 31], 107: [17, 701, 71], 109: [19], 113: [113, 131, 311], 127: [271], 137: [317, 173], 139: [193], 149: [419, 941, 491], 151: [151], 157: [571, 751], 163: [613, 631], 167: [617, 761], 179: [971, 197, 719], 181: [811, 181], 191: [191, 911], 199: [919, 991, 199]}........
```

Now, I want to delete the key if the length of the key and the length of the element of the lists of items are different. So, the desired result will be

```
d = {11: [11], 13: [31], 17: [71],37: [73], 79: [97],113: [113, 131, 311], 127: [271], 137: [317, 173], 139: [193], 149: [419, 941, 491], 151: [151], 157: [571, 751], 163: [613, 631], 167: [617, 761], 179: [971, 197, 719], 181: [811, 181], 191: [191, 911], 199: [919, 991, 199]}
```

Here if we see, the keys 101,107,103 got excluded because the length of the element inside the list item is not equal to the length of the key.

Here keys are the prime numbers and the list items are their permutation. Permutated primes are omitted.

I have tried using nested loop but didn't get the desired result.

```
for key in dict:# for each key
    for value in key:
        if len(str(value)) == len(key): 
            ... something like that i am trying
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives what you are looking for:

```
d = {10: [10, 12], 20: [43, 53], 101: [12, 213], 120: [56, 23]}

l=[] #list for keys
for key in d: #for each key
    if len(d[key]) > 0:
        for item in d[key]:
            if len(str(key)) != len(str(item)): #if the length of key is different from length of element in the list
                try:
                    l.index(key) #see if they key is already there
                except: #if not
                    l.append(key) #add key to list

for k in l: #for each key in the list
    del d[k] #delete key

print(d)
```

It gives back a dictionary with items that contain elements which ALL match the length of the key.

Comment: thanks but that also remove some of my key that should be in. Suppose d={2: [], 3: [], 5: [], 7: [], 11: [11], 13: [31], 17: [71], 19: [], 23: [], 29: [], 37: [73], 41: [], 43: [], 47: [], 53: [], 59: [], 61: [], 67: [], 79: [97], 83: [], 89: [], 101: [11, 101], 103: [13, 31], 107: [17, 701, 71], 109: [19], 113: [113, 131, 311], 127: [271], 137: [317, 173], 139: [193].... but using the aforementioned condition i get, {107: [17, 701, 71], 113: [113, 131, 311], 149: [419, 941, 491], 179: [971, 197, 719], 199: [919, 991, 199]}. But I should get the two digit also

Comment: all of the 2 digit keys in that example have a list with only 1 or 0 elements so they should not be returned. If this is not the result you are looking for please further clarify the question.

Comment: sorry for being late. okay here is the thing. I have a dictionary containing the permutations as the item values.   Suppose the dict={2: [], 3: [], 5: [], 7: [], 11: [11], 13: [31], 17: [71], 19: [], 23: [], 29: [], 37: [73], 41: [], 43: [], 47: [], 53: [], 59: [], 61: [], 67: [], 79: [97], 83: [], 89: [], 101: [11, 101], 103: [13, 31], 107: [17, 701, 71], 109: [19], 113: [113, 131, 311], 127: [271], 137: [317, 173], 139: [193], 149: [419, 941, 491], 151: [151], 157: [571, 751]........    it will exclude 103,107,101.. but the above code is removing the two digit keys also. these all are prime

Comment: why would it not exclude 101 though? please further explain the rule for inclusion/exclusion. I do not understand what warrants a deletion.

Comment: okay, extremely sorry actually for not clarifying it clearly. the above all solutions are based on the length of the list rather than the length of the element of the list. If you see the above example, for 101 the length of the key is different from the length of the element in the list item. 11 has different length.  Again same for 107. Here 17 's length is not same as the key's length. But for key 17 or 37 the length is similar to it's item, so it should be included and the 101, 103, 107... should be exlcluded

Comment: I see, I will try to edit my answer to give a new solution

Comment: @AlienwareR please review my edited answer. that code will give all keys that have a list where all elements in the list match the length of the key.

Comment: if this is still not what you are looking for, please edit your question to include the second dictionary you mentioned in the comments as well as it's expected output and I will take one more look at it.

Comment: This also retains items with no values e.g. `2: []` and `3: []`. Is that a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the goal is to retain an item in the dict if the number of digits in the item's key equals the number of elements in the item's value.

You can use a simple dict comprehension, as follows:

```
d = {10: [10, 12], 20: [43, 53], 101: [12, 213], 120: [56, 23]}

d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(str(k)) == len(v)}
# Result: {10: [10, 12], 20: [43, 53]}
```

If, instead, your requirement is to retain an item if all of the numbers in the item's value (which itself is an array of numbers) have the same length as the key, then you can use this:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if len(v) > 0 and all(len(str(n)) == len(str(k)) for n in v)}
# Result: {10: [10, 12], 20: [43, 53]}
```

Comment: thanks but if I had other keys like 12:[21], 43:[34] the aforementioned comprehension also remove those key. How will I exclude this?

Comment: You'll need to clarify what your requirement is. Why would `12:[21]` be retained? What is your precise rule for retaining an item?

Comment: okay here is the thing. I have a dictionary containing the permutations as the item values.   Suppose the dict={2: [], 3: [], 5: [], 7: [], 11: [11], 13: [31], 17: [71], 19: [], 23: [], 29: [], 37: [73], 41: [], 43: [], 47: [], 53: [], 59: [], 61: [], 67: [], 79: [97], 83: [], 89: [], 101: [11, 101], 103: [13, 31], 107: [17, 701, 71], 109: [19], 113: [113, 131, 311], 127: [271], 137: [317, 173], 139: [193], 149: [419, 941, 491], 151: [151], 157: [571, 751], 163: [613, 631]........         it will exclude 103,107,101.. but the above code is removing the two digit keys also. This all are prime.